# 404 while trying to generate pdf with reportlab

Tags: django, django-views, reportlab

I am trying to implement option to generate pdf file for download from `views.py`. For now I am using sample code provided in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-pdf/) however for some reason when I try to generate sample pdf I get 404 error with message that:

```
The current path, stv/DRG_result, didn't match any of these.

--bunch of urls paths--

The current path, stv/DRG_result, didn't match any of these.
```

That seems logical, because I did not set any path in `urls.py` for that (since there was no info that it is needed).
Should I set it? Can somebody tell me how to do it correctly, since I am very new to django. Or error is somewhere else?

My relevant `views.py` part:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas 

def DRG_result(request):

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    p.drawString(100, 100, "hello world.")

    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

Code part for the button from the template which calls this function:

```
    <form action='DRG_result' method='GET'>     
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" >Generuoti PDF</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can generate pdf using  xhtml2pdf. I spent some time with report lab but  failed to generate pdf  with views.py

Comment: I thought about using WeasyPrint library (it is even suggested by xhtml2pdf developers in most cases), but installation seemed to complicated for newbie like me. For now I will try to use reportlab. In case I will fail to adjust it to my need I might try something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to amend `urls.py` file. Turn out I needed to add this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^DRG_result/$', views.DRG_result, name='DRG_result'),
]
```